# how to use spring boot to run neo4j queries in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j

I spent a while trying to figure out spring boot neo4j in java. What I want is something like this

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Record;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.StatementResult;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Value;


public class adding {

    static Driver driver;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException {
        StatementResult result;
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j","password"));
        Session session = driver.session();

        result = session.run("CREATE (a:Person {name: bob} return a.name");

    }

}
```

So this works an all however I'm looking to query with spring boot.

I followed this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/

and was left pretty confused. I'm not sure how I can immitate the above create process with spring boot . Is there like a query command?

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringGraphNeo4jApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringGraphNeo4jApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The demo has this file and runs on a port.... I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add @EnableNeo4jRepositories in you SpringGraphNeo4jApplication class

In case you want to use your own queries , use [@query](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) annotation on repository

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories
public class SpringGraphNeo4jApplication {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringGraphNeo4jApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringGraphNeo4jApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: added query execution part

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Might be a dumb question... but I'm just wondering how I would create "result = session.run("CREATE (a:Person {name: "bob"});" this result with @query

Comment: download complete example mentioned in guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/ the git URL for same is https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-neo4j.git, it example saves and retrieves the data